# Cygwin alternate for windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

I would like to have some of the most frequent commands which I use in Linux environment in my windows box , I know there is program called Cygwin. But I don't want to use such a heavy one . All I want is a simple ported unix commands for windows.

Is there any Utilities like that ?

PS: I've created my own 'clear' command through clear.bat with 'cls' in it and I can't do it for all commands :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a few alternatives:

- [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)
- [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)
- [Microsoft Windows Services for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/interopmigration/bb380242%28en-us%29.aspx)

Out of those, perhaps [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) might serve you best.

Comment: Superuser doesn't list that when I posted this! Anyhow UnxUtils serves it :)

Comment: Sweet. I think that I'll start using that too.

Comment: The linked question has now been deleted, thanks SuperUser mods.

Comment: @dthree: Please don't sneak in spam by editing questions and adding a link to your own product.  The OP of this highly upvoted and accepted answer did not recommend your product and you did not disclose your connection to it.

Answer (score 7):

**MSYS** - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys

Quite usable, and as long as you have the "bin" directory of MSYS in %PATH%, you can use many of the unix commands from within cmd.exe.

You can even quickly switch to bash from within cmd.exe when you need to.

Comment: Cygwin allows you to use UNIX commands from within cmd.exe when you have the "bin" directory in `PATH`

Comment: MSYS works really well for porting Unix software into Windows.  Many times a ./configure and a make is all you need to build it Windows.  You also won't need that crazy Cygwin .dll to distribute with the .exe's you build.  I highly recommend MSYS.

Answer (score 4):

**UnixUtils**

- http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

A few people have suggested UnixUtils, but it doesn't seem to have been updated in several years.

[GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) seems to be under more active development.  Its [auto-updater, GetGnuWin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), is relatively clunky, but you should be able to deal with it if you're comfortable enough with the CLI to want Linux command-line tools in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you install the windows version of [git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) it comes with BASH, grep, and a bunch of other basic unix utils. It has to since git is built on those command-line tools. Easiest way to get a basic bash shell that I know of.

Comment: Actually, it comes with a subset of MSYS from MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent option is UWIN from David Korn at AT&T.  It is free and it is regularly updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have use both Cygwin and various iterations of Inerix/SFU/SUA as well as CMD + unxutils and putty, etc. It always feels like fighting the system.

I have really been won over by powershell (despite the name). I now just use powershell with some unixy aliases, a handful of scripts to emulate unixy behaviors and a few native windows ports like vim, infozip, ncftp, curl, wget, etc.

It kind of depends on what you are trying to do. If you want windows to actually be unix then nothing will feel quite right and it will be various flavors of frustrating. If you want to port software then there are lots of options with various pros and cons. If what you want is a powerful text-mode shell and scriping environment where you have a hope of replicating your automations onto servers or your buddies machines then take a hard look at powershell.